# How are many to many relations used in practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a webapplication as a school project. And I've found no way of implementing many to many relationships in any practical manner

This is my first time working in ASP.NET core. I've tried looking at existing resources but none have been able to answer my question

```
viewmodel.Spelers = new List<Speler>(from ss in _context.Spelspelers
                                             join s in _context.Spelers on ss.SpelerID equals s.SpelerID
                                             join sp in _context.Spellen on ss.SpelID equals sp.SpelID
                                             where ss.SpelID == id
                                             select s);
```

I expected to get a list of all Spelers associated with Spel but instead I get the error message:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   lambda_method(Closure )
>
> InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. To show additional information call EnableSensitiveDataLogging() when overriding DbContext.OnConfiguring.

Comment: Since you already have the correct `SpelID`, you don't need the `Spellen` table at all. Just join `Spelers` and `SpelSpelers` and filter by `ss.SpelID`. I'm not sure what is causing the error message but it might well be that you're trying to load unnecessary data.

Comment: I forgot to add a part of the error message. That was my mistake. Editing it in now. I rewrote the LINQ query as you recommended but the error persists.

Comment: The code works as intended with your alterations and the error message has stopped showing up.